# how to edit and change only "function" and "class" keyword to bold in sublime-text-2?

Tags: text, editor, sublimetext2, text-editor

i have searched through search engine and didnt find my solution for changing only the "function" and "class" keyword to bold in sublime text 2(especially for php)

all i know is how to change all text/code to bold is by adding the user settings

`font_options: ["bold"]`

but i dont know how to change only specific keyword to become bold.

so the question is :
- how to edit sublime-text-2 so it displays keyword "function" and "class" to **bold**

**edited**

whenn i change the font_options to ==> `font_options: ["bold"]`

ST2 displays `function` and `class` keyword in italic, then i tried to install ST2 in windows and it displays `function` and `class` keyword in italic too.

So i copy the theme xml file from windows to my ubuntu and nothing happen when in normal font , still the same, no italic/bold keywords , just displaying different colors for each keyword

is this normal thing? my main install ST2 is in `ubuntu 12.04 64 bit LTS`

Answer (score 2):

Open your theme file (`<sublime text 2 config folder>/Packages/Color Schemes - Default/themename.tmTheme`) and change this key:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Class name</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>entity.name.class</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>underline</string> <!-- This thing -->
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#69D2E7</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: ok so i edited the xml `<string>underline</string>` to `<string>bold</string>` and restarted ST2 but it doesnt work, changing it to `<string>italic</string>` doesn't work either

Comment: i tried to install in windows and it displays `class` and `function` keyword in italic (default) but in my ubuntu, it doesnt display those keywords like it does in windows.. But when i change the `font_options` to Bold, it does it the same like windows..

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from [ST Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8411#p34823):

For bold (or, similarly, for italic) to work you need:

- A color scheme that uses bold.
- A monospace font.
- A font that includes bold weight.